# How to get documents from Firestore where a field which is an array matches a string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all documents (products) from the `Firestore` and then show them in the `recyclerVieww`. The criterion is that the value that I have should match with the one in the 'deliverable', where the deliverable is an array.
So, get all the documents from the collection 'products' where the value in the field 'deliverable match the one I provide.
I have tried the following but I don't get any result as I expected. Am I doing it wrong?

Can someone help me with it?

```
    fun getProductsDeliverable(deliverable: String) {
          mFireStore.collection("products")
            .whereEqualTo("deliverable_mun_pan", deliverable).get().addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    for (document in it.result) {

                        val product = document.toObject(Product::class.java)
                        product.product_id = document.id
                        productsList.add(product)

                    }
                } else {

                    Log.d("TAG", "There are no items")
                }

                srProductsList.addAll(srProductsList)
                successProductsList(srProductsList)

            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is known as an [array membership query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) in Firestore, and can be done with

```
mFireStore.collection("products")
          .whereArrayContains("deliverable", "Pune")
```

So this matches products where the `deliverable` array contains a value of `"Pune"`. Instead of the hard-coded value, you can also specify your `deliverable` variable of course.